# R boot package: not enough memory to get confidence intervals

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap, large-data

I have run a rather large bootstrap in R with the boot package.

When I first ran boot() I got this:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.8 Gb
```

So, to get the boot object I had to use 'simple=TRUE', which tells boot() to not allocate all the memory at the beginning (according to ?boot). This worked fine, though it took a few minutes.

Now I need to get confidence intervals:

```
> boot.ci(vpe.bt, type="bca", simple=TRUE)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.8 Gb
```

Same problem! but according to ?boot.ci, there is no 'simple=TRUE' flag that you can use with this function (I've tried it).

So, is there any way around this using boot.ci()?

And, if not, what can I do to increase the amount of memory it can use?

Comment: Sorry, I should probably mention I am running this in Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: you can increase memory by typing memory.limit(4000), for example, which will increase R's memory to 4Gb. Obviously, you can't go above whatever memory limit your own computer has. As for your error, I'm not familiar with this function, but maybe you are doing too many bootstrap replications? I've seen this error when I've tried to create too big of a matrix.

Comment: Perhaps this should go in StackOverflow? The question is about R programming rather than statistics.

Comment: @Alan, as far as I can see from the R code it may be the use of `type = "bca"` in `boot.ci` that causes the large memory allocation. I only looked at this briefly, but try another `type` argument and see if you still have allocation problems.

Comment: @Alan H. stupid question, but do you have 2.8GB of unused RAM when issuing this command? Running top in terminal will show you the memory usage.

Comment: @Alan in addition, clear all non essential objects from the workspace before running boot, as if you need to run for loops they will take a horrendous amount of memory on big matrices

Comment: SO seems likely to generate some more constructive ideas, so let's migrate.

Comment: At a bare minimum you can try `debug(boot.ci)` and then try again and see where exactly in `boot.ci` the problem occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Calculating bca (adjusted bootstrap percentile) confidence intervals in R requires the creation of an 'importance array' which has dimensions (number of observations) x (number of reps). If you don't have enough memory to handle at least two copies of such a matrix, the function will not work.

However, normal based (type='normal') and percentile based confidence intervals (type='percent') should work.

Comment: I believe it's type = 'perc' (not 'percent') at least in boot version 1.3-20.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the boot.ci but the I've had similar problems with large vectors in my 32-bit Ubuntu system. The 32-bit systems have a limited address space which is resolved in 64-bit system.

There are some downsides with 64-bits, the main one being that it still isn't standard and that not every software provider has a 64-bit compiled version of their software, the Flash player has the last I've heard only a beta-version for 64-bit. This is usually amendable though through installing a library that allows you to run 32-bit software on a 64-bit system (although with a performance penalty).

These resources might perhaps add shed some more light on the issue:

- http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit